# Drawing boundry around heterogeneously textured tissue in microscopy study

Tags: python, opencv

I am in the process of putting together an OpenCV script to analyze immunohistochemically stained heart tissue. Our staining procedure renders cell types expressing certain proteins in their plasma membranes with pigments visible under a light microscope, which we use to photograph the images.

So far, I've succeded in segmenting the images to different layers based on color range using a modified version of the frequently cited color segmentation script available through the OpenCV community(http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html).

A screen shot of the original image:
[image: Original Image of heart tissue]

B-Cell layer displayed:
[image: AP Pigment layer]

At this point, I would like to calculate the ratio of area of B-Cells to unstained tissue. This operation prompted an extraction of the background cell layer as such based on color range:
[image: tissue background]

Obviously, these results leave much to be desired.

**Does anyone have ideas of how to approach this problem? Again, I would like to segment the background tissue (transparent) layer, which is unfortunately fairly sponge-like in texture. My goal is to create a mask representive of the area of unstained tissue.** It seems a blur technique is necessary to fill the gaps in the tissue, but the loss in accuracy this approach entails is obvious.

Comment: Using a format like jpg will introduce compression artifacts, and they may in turn affect the accuracy of your method.

Comment: How about TIF? Can you provide reference to a review of compression artifact?

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact) wiki page. I think any lossless compression would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sample image, the channels look highly correlated. If you apply decorrelation-stretching to the image you should be able to see more detail. [Here](http://dhanushkadangampola.blogspot.com/2015/02/decorrelation-stretching.html) in my blog post I've implemented decorrelation-stretching in C++ (unfortualtely not Python).

Using the sample code in the blog I did the following to segment the cell region:

- dstretch the CIE Lab image with following targetMean and tergetSigma.

  ```
  float mu[3] = {128.0f, 128.0f, 128.0f};
  float sd[3] = {128.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f};
  Mat mean = Mat(3, 1, CV_32F, mu);
  Mat sigma = Mat(3, 1, CV_32F, sd);
  ```
- Convert the dstretched CIE Lab image back to BGR.
- Erode this BGR image with a 3x3 rectangular structuring element once.
- Apply kmeans clustering to this eroded image with k = 2.

I don't know how good this segmentation is. I think it is possible to get a better segmentation by trying different values for the above parameters (mean, sigma, structuring element size and number of times the image is eroded).

(*Following images are not to the original scale*)

Original:
[image: original]
dstretched CIE Lab converted back to BGR:
[image: dstretched-cielab]
Eroded:
[image: eroded]
kmeans with k = 2:
[image: labels]

Comment: Do you recommend any particular means of implementing your c++ code in a python environment? Cython?

Comment: @DavidShaked I'm sorry, I don't have much exposure to Python. May be it's easier to code in Python, as you can see, there's not much code in C++. I found [this](https://github.com/lukassparrow/decorrstretch) while searching a Python implementation. Having said that, if you find a post (question or answer) useful in stackoverflow, consider up-voting it. If an answer to your question is acceptable, consider accepting the answer. That's how this ecosystem usually works. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @dhanushka. I wanted to hold off from marking the question as answered until I found a way to convert the C++ to something that could interface with python. To be clear, do you think the implementation you shared in your last response captures the capabilities of your C++ demo? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @DavidShaked I have limited Python knowledge. The shared python code may not be the same as my C++ implementation. With the help of this Python code and my C++ code, you should be able to do the necessary modifications. Also, as i mentioned in an earlier comment, try to use a lossless compression format for your images.